# TCP client/server application using POSIX sockets: Server not receiving 2nd packet sent

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm writing a 2D RPG game in pure ANSI C, and I've decided to implement multiplayer, so I've written boilerplate POSIX code for the client and server, and implemented a login packet. The login packet works fine, however with the addition of a logout packet when the client quits, the server never receives it.

I've stepped through in a debugger and when the `write` call is executed on the client socket the file descriptor is zero. I also set a memory watchpoint on the variable holding the client socket file descriptor, and it was never touched. I'm not sure whether this is a C bug, or something in networking I'm missing so I'm looking for a pointer of how to go about fixing it.

Creating client socket:

```c
  struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;

  client = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (client < 0) {
    perror("");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(&sockaddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

  sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, server, &sockaddr.sin_addr);

  if (connect(client, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
    perror("");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

Creating server socket:

```c
  struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
  server = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (server < 0) {
    perror("");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(&sockaddr, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

  sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

  if (bind(server, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
    perror("");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int flags = fcntl(server, F_GETFL, 0);
  flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
  if (fcntl(server, F_SETFL, flags) < 0) {
    perror("");
  }
```

Listening on server socket:

```c
  if (listen(server, maxClients) < 0) {
    perror("");
    close(server);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

...

Main loop (threaded for future offline support):

```c
void *mainLoop(void *argv) {
  void (*packetHandler)(void) = argv;

  for (;;) {
    serverClient = accept(server, NULL, NULL);
    printf("%d\n", serverClient);
    if (serverClient < 0) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    (*packetHandler)();

#ifdef SHUTDOWN
    if (shutdown(serverClient, SHUT_RDWR) < 0) {
      close(serverClient);
      close(server);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
#endif
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Writing to sockets is done using standard read and write calls.
Note: The `#ifdef` block with `SHUTDOWN` is normally not compiled.

Comment: reeeee, Show some code

Comment: A socket descriptor of zero is technically legal, but it doesn't sound right at all. Have you reported the descriptor value immediately after creating?  But showing a minimal reproducible example of actual code would help a lot.

Comment: Added code, I have outputted the value right after creating. Whilst the login packet is sent, it is 4 (obviously might vary), but then on the logout packet it's 0. Checked with Valgrind for any wacky leaks.